# What is the sample space and sigma algebra for a continuous probability measure?

Tags: probability-theory

If I were to write the sample space and sigma algebra for continuous probability measure like the Lebesgue measure on real numbers in [0,1], what would it be?

Comment: Lebesgue measure on what? Lebesgue measure on the real line is not a probability measure.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, I missed that point. I have updated the question.

Comment: Take the sample space as $[0,1]$, sigma algebra as either the Borel sigma algebra or the sigma algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets and the probability measure as Lebesgue measure.  The identity map will then be a random variable with Lebesgue measure as its distribution.